# TexMaker failing to generate PDF

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I have been working to try to add the bibliography to my thesis, but after getting Biber to work as my referencing platform, I have been unable to generate a PDF for my thesis and I believe it is failing to read \begin{document}, but I am unable to make sense of the error that it is giving me.

The error code is below:

! File ended while scanning use of \field.

\par
l.38 \begin{document}
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop. I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious, you'd better type` E' or `X' now and fix your file.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 38.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 38.

This is the code for the section prior to this error:

```
\documentclass[article,
  normalmargins,
  10pt,
  openany,
  onehalfspacing,
]{ut-thesis}
% packages
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % for links
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex} % for references
\usepackage{graphicx} % for embedding graphics
\usepackage{booktabs} % for pretty tables
\usepackage{lipsum} % for gibberish text
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
%\bibliography{Bib\Rerences.bib}


% author data
\author{}
\title{}
\degree{}
\department{}
\gradyear{}
% reference database
\addbibresource{Bib/References.bib}

\begin{document}
```

At this point, I am clueless on what the problem with my code is. This error started after I finished changing the TexMaker configuration to the following:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an error in the bib. Do you have fields (e.g. abstract fields) that contain e.g. percent chars?

Comment: I do have % signs in the bibliography, but manually cleaning that up to change all occurrences to \% does not help.

Would removing all of these be better than \%?

Comment: `\%` should work. But better delete the faulty bbl and recompile so that the changes are also applied.

Comment: Updating the script to instead read past the bibliography does not appear to repair the problem. I simply changed \addbibresource{Bib/References.bib} into %\addbibresource{Bib/References.bib}

Comment: Delete the bbl!

Comment: You are right, the .bbl was the problem. I guess there was a missing } somewhere in the document. Thank you!